# What does the assembly code `movl %1, %%ebx` mean?

Tags: gcc, assembly, linux-kernel, inline-assembly

I'm trying to understand some assembly code:

```
movl $244, %eax
movl %1, %%ebx
```

The first one means put number 244 to the register eax, but what does second mean? thanks in advance for any help

```
P.S see the difference %1 and $244 and %eax and %%ebx
```

Comment: I retag because you forgot to tell that this assembly code is used in context of inline-assembly

Answer (score 4):

The %1 is used by gcc inline assembly to specify parameter.
You will find some hint about inline assembly here :

http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s4

Comment: Note that the newest gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) really go into detail about all this.

Answer (score 3):

`movl %1, %%ebx`

`movl` will move the first parameter to the second parameter. The first parameter is the variable `%1`. The second parameter is the register `%%ebx`. The compiler will change the double percent sign to a single percent sign so you could just as good write:

`movl %1, %ebx`

Comment: Umm, actually I don't believe you can remove that extra % (you get "operand number missing after %-letter").  If you are using extended asm (which OP is as indicated by the %1), you MUST use `%%ebx`.  The reason the %eax gets away with this is that OP is copying this from somewhere else (ie not extended asm).